# using AtomikosDataSourceBean to configure jta transaction manager?

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

I have below spring configuration and am using Spring3.

```
<util:properties id="remoteEnv">
    <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://jndi.myURL.me:1099</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
    <prop key="jnp.disableDiscovery">true</prop>
</util:properties>
```

Now i would like to use Spring `JTATransactionManager` using `AtomikosDataSourceBean`. How can i cofigure It?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot... You ahve a jboss transaction manager that isn't going to work with the `AtomikosDataSourceBean`. The latter is only intended to be used with Atomikos itself. As mentioned in your other question you need to configure the datasources also in JBoss and do a lookup (why don't you just deploy in jboss instead of tomcat btw?!).

Comment: Deinum, one application is deployed in JBoss and am getting its access using JNDI look up. My application is using it and mine is deployed in Tomcat. Is it difficult to get it working with JTA ?